# How to type umlauts with long key press?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

On Mac, Android and iOS if you long press <kbd>a</kbd> you see something like this
[image]

Is there an easy way to set up something similar on Ubuntu? I don't even want that fancy bubble. It's enough to replace `a` to `ä` on long press.

I don't want to use the Compose Key or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> for this.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the US International keyboard with dead keys. Then `'a` will give you `á` and `"a` will give you `ä`.

I use that too.